# Is it slower to have a function call inside a function when there is no need?

Tags: php, function

This has been bothering me, lets say I have a function:

```
public function addItem($item) {
   $this->items[] = $item;
   return $this;
}
```

and then I have another function like:

```
public function addItems($items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $this->addItem($item); //IS THIS FASTER OR
        $this->items[] = $item;//THIS?
    }

    return $this;
}
```

basically I always do the option 1 `$this->addItem($item)` inside loop but on the other hand it seems to me redundant I could just append item to array essentially it does samething. Just want to know which one is faster if there is any difference in performance.

Comment: Why not use `microtime(true)` to time it yourself?

Comment: Better yet use a real profiler and look at the big picture, instead of guess-optimizing minutiae.

Comment: good point, which I will do but I also want to know if in theory function call is slower than just appending it to array

Comment: your calling a function and appending a value vs just appending a value... of course the second is faster

Comment: thanks guys I guess I'll go with having cleaner code since If I ever need to modify the way its inserted into array would have to modify both function rather than just modifying one

Comment: Super duper micro optimizations... in the end, does it really matter? I think this question falls into personal preference and code separation/modularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
$this->items[] = $item;
```

Will always be (minutely) faster than

```
$this->addItem($item);
```

Because the second version incurs the overhead of calling a function, whereas the first does not. It is the same reason you should use the first version instead of [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/array_push) for one element. Quoting the manual:

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's
> better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of
> calling a function.

Comment: +1 but I feel this is perhaps over simplistic. `Will always be (minutely) faster than ...` _where the function contains the same code_ - it would be illogical for adding something (a function call) to reduce execution time. Or: 1+1 is obviously more than 1.

Answer (score 3):

Function calls require some processor time. So, less function calls -> more performance.

**HOWEVER**

The main point is that your code remains **clear and secure**. Such a code is much more important than any performance.

Remember once and forever:

> Clear code, clear variable and function names in
>   your code will save you HUGE amounts of time and health.

Your case: `addItem()` function provides a really **good abstraction**. Just keep it.

In function `addItem()` you could do some validation and debug things. Also, it can return `true` or `false` indicating success.

Answer (score 2):

Function jump is in principle slower than direct access (i.e., 1 is faster).
That being said:

1. Don't worry about micro optimizations. Prefer clear, clean, concise and/or flexible code to fast code.
2. If you use some PHP opcode optimizer, chances are those accesses are inlined. In that case, there would be no difference.

Comment: Any reasons for downvoting? I liked the 666 reputation!

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing I ever learned about benchmarking was

**Never believe what anybody tells you about what is faster or slower until you prove it yourself**

I have since wrote dozens of benchmarks and proved public opinion wrong many times.

Comment: well, on your system at least. that said, this doesn't answer the question ... the second way is obviously faster because there's no overhead from calling a function. you don't need to test that to know it's true.

Comment: oh, i'm not doubting that most people on the internet don't know what they're talking about

Comment: @sgroves - Wait, you mean [somebody is wrong on the Internet???](http://xkcd.com/386/)